# RabbitMQ+TLS: ssl_upgrade_error

Tags: ssl, rabbitmq, rabbitmqctl

Following the directions stated [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html), I have set up a certificate authority and created the `rabbitmq.config` with the appropriate fields. However, when I try to connect to the RabbitMQ server with

```
openssl s_client -connect 127.0.0.1:5671 -tls1
```

I get the following in standard output:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
write:errno=104
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 0 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID: 
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1449612785
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

and I see the following error in the logs:

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 8-Dec-2015::16:13:10 ===
Error on AMQP connection <0.257.0>:
{ssl_upgrade_error,
    {options,
        {cacertfile,"/home/nthompson/learn_celery/testca/cacert.pem",
            {error,eacces}}}}
```

What could be the problem?

I have tried the following, with no success:

- Open up the permissions of `cacert.pem`, i.e., I ran `chmod 444 cacert.pem` as well as some more hopeless permissions, no dice.
- Validated that all intermediate directories have permissions of 775.
- Validated that the RabbitMQ server was indeed listening on port 5671, and it was:

  ```
  $ sudo rabbitmq status
  {listeners,[{clustering,25672,"::"},{amqp,5672,"::"},{'amqp/ssl',5671,"::"}]},
  ```
- Checked all paths in `rabbitmq.config`, and loosened up the certificate exchange policy by setting `{verify,verify_none}` and `{fail_if_no_peer_cert,false}`.
- Enabled the use of the `rabbitmq_auth_mechanism_ssl` plugin via

  ```
  $ sudo rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_auth_mechanism_ssl
  ```

  and verified that it was picked up by `rabbitmq-server`. In addition, I added `{auth_mechanisms, ['PLAIN', 'AMQPLAIN', 'EXTERNAL']}` to the `rabbitmq.config`.
- RabbitMQ version is 3.5.4 (default apt-get), but I also upgraded to 3.5.6 (latest) to see if this would go away.

Comment: Have you tried the things listed here? https://www.rabbitmq.com/troubleshooting-ssl.html

Comment: Did you manage to solve the problem? I have the exact same one and the troubleshooting page from rabbitMQ is completely useless.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of messing around and searching I FINALLY got it!

In my case, the issue was caused by the certification files ownership and permissions.

I edited my `/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config` so that the certificate, key and CAfile pointed to `/etc/rabbitmq/conf/<file>.pem`, copied the original `.pem` files in `/etc/rabbitmq/conf/` then I `chown -R rabbitmq:rabbitmq /etc/rabbitmq/conf` and restarted the service `service rabbitmq-server restart` and it worked.